# cURL not working on hosting (public)

Tags: php, curl, server

I have to reach the host http://80.16.95.5:8180/jalbopretorio/AlboPretorio on 8180 port with a command cURL....

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

In local (debug) I get an answer in less than 1 sec.
On my hosting (aruba and register) I can not recover data.
Test here: http://www.studiozucchetto.it/opendata/getting_test.php

Why? There are some rules that prevent you from reaching that url / port

PS. Always in the same pag. there is an  iframe that loads the content of the requested URL ... and this is loaded instantly. Mah! I do not understand

Comment: you have to enable curl in your provider

Comment: Your host is probably blocking outbound traffic to non-standard ports. Try `curl --head http://80.16.95.5:8180/jalbopretorio/AlboPretorio` from the command line on the server and/or dump the contents of `curl_getinfo($ch)` at the end of your script.